# Prevent display all the dropdown-toggles when I click one dropdown-toggle

Tags: jquery, css, bootstrap-4

When I click one dropdown-toggle it is being displaying but the problem is that all the rest of dropdown-toggles are displaying:

[image]

This is my code:

```
    <ul class="list-unstyled components">
        <p class="user-dash"><span><img class="img-fluid" src="{{ url('/img/freddy.png') }}"></span><a href="{{ route('admin') }}">Freddy Alcarazo</a></p>
        <li class="active">
            <a href="#homeSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle"><span><i class="fas fa-home"></i></span> Home</a>
            <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="homeSubmenu">
                <li>
                    <a href="{{ route('admin') }}">Home</a>
                </li>
                
            </ul>
        </li>

        
        <li>
            <!-- <a href="#"><span class="ti-info-alt mr-2"></span>About</a>-->
            <a href="#pageSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle"><span class="fas fa-users"></span> Candidatos</a>
            <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="pageSubmenu">
                <li>
                    <a href="{{ route('admin.candidates.index') }}">Candidatos</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="{{ route('admin.candidates.create') }}">Nuevo Candidato</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>

    
        <li>
            <a href="#pageSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle"><span class="fas fa-graduation-cap"></span> Profesiones</a>
            <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="pageSubmenu">
                <li>
                    <a href="{{ route('admin.professions.index') }}">Profesiones</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="{{ route('admin.professions.create') }}">Nueva Profesión</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>

        <li>
            <a href="#pageSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle">&nbsp<span class="fas fa-book"></span> Áreas</a>
            <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="pageSubmenu">
                <li>
                    <a href="{{ route('admin.areas.index') }}">Áreas</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="{{ route('admin.areas.create') }}">Nueva Área</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
       
    </ul>
```

The problem is here:

```
 <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="pageSubmenu">
```

All this has the same id "pageSubmenu" if I changue it the dropdown-toggle stops his visualization and I can't see his subitems.

I tried it using jquery:

```
 <script>
        $('#pageSubmenu').on("click", function(e) {
         
            e.stopPropagation();
        });
    </script>
```

but it don't work. Any idea about how prevent this problem, I will appreciate.. thanks

Comment: *All this has the same id "pageSubmenu"* ?? ID should be unique so don't use same id for more than one element

Comment: yes, but if I change it isn't displayed. I'm using this template https://gist.github.com/krystinalynn/43d76c05fc0601dbb2c9a18134bc672b I just added more submenus.. but changing the id nothing happens.

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef here is the template https://bootstrapious.com/tutorial/sidebar/index.html

Comment: The template works fine .. But when you copy/paste the same code you copied with same href and id .. So need to change  `<a href="#pageSubmenu"` and `<ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="pageSubmenu">` the href and id should be the same for each `<a>` and next  `<ul>` but should be different for each  `<li>`.. It means `href="#anything1"` , `id="anything1"` the next will be  `href="#anything2"` , `id="anything2"`

Comment: I didn't have noticed of that bro, minutes ago I was looking for another template I found something called adminLtev3 but it has big size a many dependecies. But using the plante of above I save disk space and is more simple.. I will keep in mind next time this trick, I'm not bootstrap or front-end developer expert,. anyways thanks bro.

Comment: You're totally welcome @Freddy .. Have a nice day and happy coding bro :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Href and Ul id should be unique, like this:

```
 <ul class="list-unstyled components">
            <p class="user-dash"><span><img class="img-fluid" src="{{ url('/img/freddy.png') }}"></span><a href="{{ route('admin') }}">Freddy Alcarazo</a></p>
            <li class="active">
                <a href="#homeSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle"><span><i class="fas fa-home"></i></span> Home</a>
                <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="homeSubmenu">
                    <li>
                        <a href="{{ route('admin') }}">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <!-- <a href="#"><span class="ti-info-alt mr-2"></span>About</a>-->
                <a href="#pageSubmenu1" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle"><span class="fas fa-users"></span> Candidatos</a>
                <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="pageSubmenu1">
                    <li>
                        <a href="{{ route('admin.candidates.index') }}">Candidatos</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="{{ route('admin.candidates.create') }}">Nuevo Candidato</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#pageSubmenu2" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle"><span class="fas fa-graduation-cap"></span> Profesiones</a>
                <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="pageSubmenu2">
                    <li>
                        <a href="{{ route('admin.professions.index') }}">Profesiones</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="{{ route('admin.professions.create') }}">Nueva Profesión</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#pageSubmenu3" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle">&nbsp<span class="fas fa-book"></span> Áreas</a>
                <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="pageSubmenu3">
                    <li>
                        <a href="{{ route('admin.areas.index') }}">Áreas</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="{{ route('admin.areas.create') }}">Nueva Área</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
```